# The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.3

Tags: c#, truevault

While embeding web with truevault for data storage, during uploading the file, and for getting document id through truevault I am getting The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request error while running the following code. while on other pages same code working fine

string documentId = "";

```
        string jsonDocument = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(NewsInfo);

        string encodedJson = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonDocument));
        string formVars = "document=" + encodedJson;
        string url = "https://api.truevault.com/v1/vaults/" + vaultId + "/documents";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Accept = "*/*";
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(apiKey + ":")));

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formVars);
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream(); //open connection
        stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); // Send the data.
        stream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string html = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            JToken token = JObject.Parse(html).SelectToken("document_id");
            documentId = (string)token;
        }

        response.Close();
        streamReader.Close();

        return documentId;
```

Comment: `catch (WebException we)
        {
            var resp = we.Response as HttpWebResponse;
        }`
Can you tell me what actual error that you are getting from applying above try..catch

Comment: I second @Avijit's ask for the request response. With any HTTP 400 responses, TrueVault's API will return the exact nature of the error in the response body.

Answer (score 0):

If you are uploading a file you probably need to use `multipart/form-data`. 
Not always, but usually, that is the right thing to do.

Also check the max size of data that is allowed by truevault.

Let me know if that helps.